# Jquery load only elements that end with a certain string

Tags: jquery

First off I am pretty new to jquery.. I want to use the .load() feature but this same file is used for several places on one page. Ideally I would like to have the #element a variable, but from playing around with it myself I don't know that I can do that. I was wondering if there is a way to have this load function apply to all elements that end with a certain string, or if you need to give it the full exact element id? I'm having a hard time putting this into words what I mean but my code may help clear it up.

```
function RateItem(varItemId, varRate)
{
$.ajax({
url:"ajax.rate.item.php",
type:"POST",
data:{item:varItemId,rating:varRate},
success:function(ReloadRating){
$("#stars").load("index.php #stars")
alert(ReloadRating);
}
});
}
```

This is for a star rating system. I have several div elements that will be using this same code, all which have an id that ends with '_stars'. In place of the #stars element I would like to have a way of calling all div elements that end with that, or ideally have something like:

```
$("varItemId + _stars").load("index.php varItemId + _stars");
```

Playing around with this for a while I didn't have any luck in getting this to work unless I specified an exact div Id. Does anyone have ideas on how to somehow make this work into a .load statement:

```
[div$='_stars']
```

Above is from [here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Comment: `div` is a tag name, while you want to filter by attribute `id`. Just use it: `[id$='_stars']`

Comment: Sweet!, that was it, thank you!@Andrei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'd need to do is first select the elements via that ends-with selector, for the `id` attribute:

```
$('[id$="_stars"]')
```

and then use that to load each url:

```
$('[id$="_stars"]').each(function() {
    $(this).load("index.php #"+this.id);
});
```

That will go through each of the elements with an ID ending with `_stars`, and for each of those elements it will load the index.php with the URL fragment set to be the same as the defined ID for the element.